# Issue while converting the date time to timestamp

Tags: php

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', '2021-07-15T19:00:00.000Z');
if ($d === false) {
    die("Incorrect date string");
} else {
    echo $d->getTimestamp();
}
```

This is not working and displayed error "Incorrect date string"

Am i missing anything?

Comment: The format don't match, `"Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000\Z"` or `15-07-2021 19:00:00`

Comment: The format "Y-m-d \ TH: i: s.000 \ Z" does not correctly take the milliseconds and the time zone into account.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What makes you think that this **should** work?

Answer (score 1):

The format is wrong.
The Date is a UTC date that use the Z (Zulu) zone designator.
The format character v can use for milliseconds and the character e for the time zone.

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.ve', '2021-07-15T19:00:00.000Z');
var_dump($d);
```

Output:

object(DateTime)#2 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2021-07-15 19:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(2) ["timezone"]=> string(1) "Z" }

The Timestamp you get with

```
$timeStamp = $d->getTimeStamp();
//1626375600
```

or with the old school function strtotime

```
$timeStamp = strtotime('2021-07-15T19:00:00.000Z');
```

The format '2021-07-15T19: 00: 00.000Z' is recognized by DateTime. This code

```
echo date_create('2021-07-15T19:00:00.000Z')->getTimeStamp();
//1626375600
```

also provides the correct timestamp.

**Please note:**

For the correct calculation of the timestamp, it is important to work with the correct time zone in addition to the date and time.
If the timezone is not correct, an incorrect time stamp is determined.
Solutions with DateTime::createFromFormat, which hide the timezone in the format with \Z, only return the correct date and often an incorrect timestamp.

Comment: I think our code is not working for this date: `2021-07-08T20:16:04.254385Z`, var_dump shows nothing??

Comment: The date "2021-07-08T20:16:04.254385Z" has 6 decimal places instead of 3. You must use the character u instead of v.

Comment: The old date & time functions, including`strtotime()`, are obsolete and do not work with timezones. Use the [date & time classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

Comment: It is always better to work with DateTime. Functions like strtotime correctly handle time zones if they are correctly included in the date string. Many solutions here at SO ignore this.
See for yourself: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/63df4a0be1762378e503aea5e40a97fa3dab908f

Answer (score -1):

It does not work because the date (`2021-07-15T19:00:00.000Z`) does not match the format (`d-m-Y H:i:s`).

Besides the visible missing `T`, `Z` and the milliseconds in the format, it does not work because the format expects the day to come first and the date starts with the year. There isn't any month in any year that have 2021 days :-)

Because your input date uses a standard format (ISO 8601), the constructor of class [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) is able to parse it without hints about the format.

Use:

```php
$d = new DateTime('2021-07-15T19:00:00.000Z');
```

The input date is expressed as relative to the UTC time zone. For computations with the date you don't need anything else. You need to use a timezone if you want to format it (to present it to the user, for example).
This is really easy, use the [`setTimeZone()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) method of `$d`and pass a [`DateTimeZone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) object, like this:

```php
$d = new DateTime('2021-07-15T19:00:00.000Z');
$d->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
echo($d->format('D, d M Y H:i:s'));
```

It prints `Thu, 15 Jul 2021 21:00:00` (the date is during the summer time and Germany is at UTC+2 during summer).

Check it [online](https://3v4l.org/BDhUn).